Element plus type errors in Vue 3 Project
I have an application that I am working on which uses Vue3, TypeScript, Vite, vue-facing-decorator and element plus. My IDE is VSCode and I have installed Vue-Official plugin.
My dependencies in package.json:
{
"dependencies": {
    "element-plus": "^2.6.1",
    "ulid": "^2.3.0",
    "vue": "^3.4.21",
    "vue-facing-decorator": "^3.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rushstack/eslint-patch": "^1.3.3",
    "@tsconfig/node20": "^20.1.2",
    "@types/jsdom": "^21.1.6",
    "@types/node": "^20.11.28",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^5.0.4",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^13.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.4.5",
    "@vue/tsconfig": "^0.5.1",
    "eslint": "^8.49.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.17.0",
    "jsdom": "^24.0.0",
    "npm-run-all2": "^6.1.2",
    "typescript": "~5.4.0",
    "vite": "^5.1.6",
    "vite-plugin-dts": "^3.7.3",
    "vitest": "^1.4.0",
    "vue-tsc": "^2.0.6"
  }
}

Now everything till 2 days ago. For some reason my VScode now gives me error on element plus tags in the html of my vue components.
Below is an example:
VsCode snippet
I have tried turning on eslint, tried to create a shims file, tried to create a global.d.ts file added configuration in tsconfig to skip lib checks and more below is my tsconfig:
{
  "extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.dom.json",
  "include": ["env.d.ts", "src/**/*", "tests/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "tsBuildInfoFile": "./node_modules/.tmp/tsconfig.app.tsbuildinfo",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "strict": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "types": ["element-plus/global"],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    },
    "verbatimModuleSyntax": false
  }
}

